# Google Sheet - Split Imported Data Into Rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet script which imports data from ChatGPT into a cell in googsheets.

```
    function GPT(prompt) {
  var API_KEY = "myapikey"
  var Model_ID = "text-davinci-002";
  var maxTokens = 64;
  var temperature = 0.5;
  // Build the API payload
var payload = {
  'model': Model_ID, // or your desired model
  'prompt': prompt,
  'temperature': temperature,
  'max_tokens': maxTokens,
};

var options = {
    "method": "post",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + API_KEY
    },
    "payload": JSON.stringify(payload)
  };

  // Make the API request
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.openai.com/v1/completions", options);

  // Parse the response and return the generated text
  var responseData = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  return responseData.choices[0].text.trim();

}
```

Within my sheet, I can then submit a query to chat gpt using;

=GPT("give me a list of 5 whatever")

The results are returned into a single cell like this;

> 1. Get around town quickly and easily with an ebike!
> 2. Save money on gas and help the environment with an ebike!
> 3. Get in shape and have fun with an ebike!
> 4. Save time and hassle with an ebike!
> 5. Make your commute easier"

Does anyone know how I could split those results so that if chat gpt returns a numbered list, the list is output into seperate rows (not in a single cell)?

Comment: About `split those results so that if chat gpt returns a numbered list`, in your situation, are there cases that the response doesn't include a list? Or, do your responses always include only one list? And, if the response includes no list and several sentences including the line breaks, what result do you want? And, if the response includes both several sentences and several lists, what result do you want? I wanted to confirm whether each list is required to be detected in each response in your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use the split() Function with "\n" as the Separator

Based from your output:

> 1. Get around town quickly and easily with an ebike!
> 2. Save money on gas and help the environment with an ebike!
> 3. Get in shape and have fun with an ebike!
> 4. Save time and hassle with an ebike!
> 5. Make your commute easier"

You can use `split("\n")` to separate the rows in the cell into different cells. Afterwards, use `map(x=>[x])` to transform your array into 2d (for Google Sheets format for 1 column multiple rows). You may use this sample script as basis:

```
function splitIntoRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = ss.getRange("A1").getValue(); //store your data to a variable
  var out = data.split("\n").map(x=>[x]); //splits the multiple row data into different cells
  ss.getRange(1,1,out.length,1).setValues(out);
}
```

### Input:

[image: input]

### Output:

[image: output]

### References:

- [split()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)
- [map()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)